# Is tsheets.intuit.com a safe website? If so, why does it try to access a chrome-extension:// url?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, appsec, web-service

This really doesn't seem safe to me, and I am wondering if there is a MITM attack happening or if this is somehow legit. I am worried something might be happening with my company's payroll data. Here is my investigation so far:

1. starting from a clean installation of ungoogled chromium, I go to `https://tsheets.intuit.com/page/login_oii`.
2. opening the devtools and going to the network tab, I reload.
3. I see this in the stream:
   [image]
   and this in the console:
   [image]
   and this in network info:
   [image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Maybe it's one of your browser plugins interfering/sinkholing the request?..

Comment: @SirMuffington It is a clean install of ungoogled chromium. no extensions installed and the only plugins are PDF readers. This still doesn't explain why a script on the page, from the domain, is trying to access a chrome URI.

Comment: I can confirm it does such request to chrome://invalid. It's not a MItM you are suffering. As to why it does so, that's anyone's guess. This code is highly minified. They may be trying to communicate with/detect a specific chrome extension or they may be interested in getting an invalid response by some reason (not too likely as it's called from a XHR) .